# Getting client-side CORS to work when provider rejects pre-flight requests due to missing authorization header

Tags: angular, rest, oauth, cors, salesforce

I am developing an Angular app that'll be consuming SalesForce API's (a.k.a. a SalesForce "Connected App"). Authentication occurs via oAuth/OpenID and works well. However, the app cannot currently access the SalesForce API endpoints succesfully, because:

1. It's a server-less app and REST calls are made client-side, **AND**
2. REST calls are "non-simple": they include custom headers (namely, the "Authorization" header which holds the oAuth access token), and thus cause the browser to issue a pre-flight OPTIONS request; **AND**
3. SalesForce rejects any API request that does not include a valid "Authorization" header and token, **including the pre-flight**, which by definition does not include the custom headers from the initial GET request (indeed the whole point of the pre-flight is to ask the server if it will allow the custom header in question).

The client app URL has been added to the CORS origin whitelist in SalesForce setup, to no effect.

This leaves me totally stuck. I can't avoid the pre-flight by removing the custom "Authorization" header from REST calls, because then the only way to transmit the oAuth token to the endpoints is in a URL parameter, which is not secure; I can't proxy the request through my own back-end (i.e., avoiding front-end CORS limitations) because it's a server-less app; and I can't make SalesForce accept the pre-flight because it's totally under the browser's control and there's no way to modify its headers.

Is there a way to configure, or coerce, SalesForce to accept pre-flight OPTIONS requests without "Authorization" headers? If not, might there be some other way for me to get out of this catch 22?

**Below is example code:**

XHR request:

```
{
  "url": "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo",
  "body": null,
  "reportProgress": false,
  "withCredentials": false,
  "responseType": "json",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "normalizedNames": [
      {
        "key": "accept",
        "value": "Accept"
      },
      {
        "key": "authorization",
        "value": "Authorization"
      }
    ],
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": [
      {
        "key": "accept",
        "value": ["application/json"]
      },
      {
        "key": "authorization",
        "value": ["Bearer [...]"] // OAuth token is here
      }
    ],
    "lazyInit": null
  },
  "params": {
    "updates": null,
    "cloneFrom": null,
    "encoder": { HttpUrlEncodingCodec },
    "map": null
  },
  "urlWithParams": "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/userinfo"
}
```

Pre-flight request to `test.salesforce.com:443` resulting from the above:

```
OPTIONS /services/oauth2/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: test.salesforce.com
Connection: close
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: [...] // client app URL is here
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.84 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Response to the pre-flight request:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 22 Dec 2017 20:16:11 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests 
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=IBrO4jKqQ6qedsWA5DFIcw;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Tue, 20-Feb-2018 20:16:11 GMT;Max-Age=5184000
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 19

Missing_OAuth_Token
```

Thanks so much in advance!

P.S: this is the first question I've ever posted on StackOverflow. I hope it meets the standards. If it doesn't I apologize in advance and I'll be happy to modify.

Comment: First, your question makes sense, so no apologies necessary! Second, I'm confused - when you make the GET request, presumably you're passing the Authorization header, right? So it should be passed automatically in the preflight OPTIONS request also... Do you have any examples of both request and response headers for the preflight OPTIONS request? I assume you're setting the withCredentials flag on your request?

Comment: Yes, my GET request includes the Authorization header, but my understanding is that pre-flight requests are always sent without any custom headers, since by definition their purpose is to ask the target of it will or won't accept a certain custom header in future requests. I believe the withCredentials flag also has no effect on pre-flight requests for this reason.

Comment: Here's the W3 spec confirming that the browser omits extra hearers from the pre-flight: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0

Comment: @nonAlgebraic hey man, any workaround for this? I'm running into the same issue here :(

Comment: I have run into exactly the same problem. Preflight OPTIONS request is getting 403 response because it does not contain the Authorization key with Bearer Token value. Did You manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I suspect you're still busy developing this application and the request is coming from `localhost`?

Also not sure if you have had a look to see what the actual response to the pre-flight was and if the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` included the PUT or GET methods you are trying to invoke?

Salesforce most definitely supports CORS, if properly setup.

In Salesforce setup you can whitelist an origin for cross-origin resource sharing (CORS), that origin will then be allowed to execute code (such as JavaScript) running in a Web browser to communicate with Salesforce.

Read more on this topic here at the Salesforce Documentation:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/extend_code_cors.htm

Comment: Yes, the client app is running on localhost. Yes, the OPTIONS pre-flight request triggered by the browser includes the "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" and "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" headers. The response to the pre-flight is a 403 Forbidden, along with an error message complaining about the absence of a valid OAuth token (i.e., an "Authorization" header - the very thing whose presence in the initiating GET requests triggered the pre-flight). Finally, yes, I have whitelisted the origin in SalesForce's CORS settings.

Comment: I have done exactly that and proceeded without issues. You will need to post some sample code @nonAlgebraic

Comment: fair enough! I've edited the OP with some sample code. Thanks for your attention.